# Calculating minimum distance using "Distance Matrix" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, distance-matrix

I want to calculate minimum distance between points and a line in QGIS. I use "Distance Matrix", point shapefile contains 1337 points data, and I made unique ID as sequence number. A line is actually coast line and I convert text file to vector, then extract nodes using "Extract Nodes".

I followed manual and tutorial, but the output is different with what I expected. They mentioned that if I want to calculate minimum distance note check k=1, but I think my result contains the farthest distance. The output file's target ID is all the same. And I wonder what is the exact meaning of *unique ID*?

Please check and advise about my actions.

Comment: I think your approach is correct. Have you made sure both your point layers have the same CRS? And both layers will need a unique value field, so you can tell which is the closest point to each of your 1337 points.. you can add a unique id to your 'extract nodes' layer using the field calculator and $rownum

Comment: You could also try v.distance in GRASS http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.distance.html